# Не могу открыть изображение Pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, pillow

Есть скрипт,который открывает изображение для обработки. Чисто технически оно должно работать..(скрипт взят из примера по лабе) но оно не работает и не делает ничего. В интерпретаторе высвечивается что компиляция произошла без ошибок.

А по задумке должно высвечиваться меню выбора файла из директории

В чем может быть проблеиа?

```py
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile, asksaveasfile
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter

def process_image_pil():
    """Load from file - process image - show image in PIL"""
    # Відкриваємо файл у бінарному режимі використовуючи діалог tkinter
    f = askopenfile(mode='r',
                    defaultextension=".jpg",
                    filetypes=(("Text files", "* .jpg"), ("All files", "*. *")))
    if f == None:
        print("Error file open")  # Якщо файл не обраний
    else:
        img = Image.open(f)  # Передаємо об'єкт файлу
        print(img.size)  # Отримуємо розмір зображення
        print(img.format)  # Виводимо формат зображення
        img1 = img.rotate(45, Image.NEAREST, expand=False)  # Повертаємо на 45, обрізаємо
        img1 = img1.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)  # Фільтр - розмиття
        img1 = img1.resize((100, 75))  # Створюємо мініатюру
        img.paste((255, 0, 0), (9, 9, 111, 86))  # Вставляємо червону рамку в верхньому лівому кутку
        img.paste(img1, (10, 10))  # Вставляємо мініатюру
        img.show()  # Показуємо у вікні
    f.close()  # Закриваємо файл
```

**UPD:**
Попробовал создать приложение с кнопкой выбора файла. Возможность выбора появилась.

```py
import tkinter
from tkinter.filedialog import askopenfile, asksaveasfile
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageFilter


class MainWindow(tkinter.Frame):
    """"Клас MainWindow, що наслідує Frame"""

    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Настройка графічного інтерфейсу"""
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.parent = parent
        # Розтягнути фрейм
        self.pack(fill=tkinter.BOTH, expand=1)
        # Розтягнути сітку
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Створення віджетів
        self.but1 = tkinter.Button(self, text="Open file", command=self.process_image_pil)
        # Розміщення віджетів в сітці основного вікна
        self.but1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tkinter.NSEW)


    def process_image_pil(self):
        """Load from file - process image - show image in PIL"""
        # Відкриваємо файл у бінарному режимі використовуючи діалог tkinter
        f = askopenfile(mode='r',
                        defaultextension=".jpg",
                        filetypes=(("Text files", "* .jpg"), ("All files", "*. *")))
        if f == None:
            print("Error file open")  # Якщо файл не обраний
        else:
            img = Image.open(f)  # Передаємо об'єкт файлу
            print(img.size)  # Отримуємо розмір зображення
            print(img.format)  # Виводимо формат зображення
            img1 = img.rotate(45, Image.NEAREST, expand=False)  # Повертаємо на 45, обрізаємо
            img1 = img1.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)  # Фільтр - розмиття
            img1 = img1.resize((100, 75))  # Створюємо мініатюру
            img.paste((255, 0, 0), (9, 9, 111, 86))  # Вставляємо червону рамку в верхньому лівому кутку
            img.paste(img1, (10, 10))  # Вставляємо мініатюру
            img.show()  # Показуємо у вікні
        f.close()  # Закриваємо файл


application = tkinter.Tk()
application.title("Lab6")
window = MainWindow(application)
application.mainloop()
```

Выводит ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Как пофиксить?**

Comment: `mode='rb'` . .